# JPA spec requiring no-arg constructor disables us to write completely correct hashcode/equals. How do you cope with that?

Tags: jpa

Ok, so here [1] is the great read, how do really correctly define hashcode/equals, namely with respect to object hierarchies. But here I'd like to ask about #pitfall 3 from that article, which shows bizarre behavior when hashcode/equals are defined on mutable fields and Set is used for collections. We cannot use final fields and parameterized constructor only, due to JPA spec. So what are the means to avoid these gotchas? What do you use?

Well, obviously one is to avoid using Set in JPA entities. Does not seems very nice. Another solution could be to "unsupport" setters after equals method was called, but that's ridiculous and equals surely shouldn't have side-effect.

So how do you cope with that? Aside from not-knowing/ignoring it, which probably would be default action in java world...

[1] https://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html

Comment: The non-arg constructor can be `protected` and you do not need any `setter` if you use `field access` behavior. Then nobody can change your `hashCode()` fields.

Comment: Use the default equals/hashCode implementations in Object for your entities. You should preserve object identity and not ever have two instances of the same entity. Overriding those methods is needed only for immutable "value" objects (as opposed to mutable "reference" objects). You should never need to directly use a Set to hold entities; the Set should be encapsulated in yet another entity container object that enforces the necessary business rules surrounding the collection of child entities.

Answer (score 0):

If entity is detached you need to override equal and hashcode[1](https://thoughts-on-java.org/ultimate-guide-to-implementing-equals-and-hashcode-with-hibernate/). Every entity has to have @Id. ID is immutable. Entities should implement equal and hashcode based on primary key ID.

Pitfall 3 deals with mutable object. Cannot by applied on entity with immutable ID.

[Guide to Implementing equals() and hashCode() with Hibernate](https://thoughts-on-java.org/ultimate-guide-to-implementing-equals-and-hashcode-with-hibernate/)